# Why is R not performing Yates correction?

Tags: r, chi-squared

I've been trying to do a chisq.test in my data:

```
x <- c("1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "2", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "1", "1", 
"1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "1", "2", "1", 
"1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", 
"1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "2", 
"2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "1", 
"1", "3", "2", "2", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", 
"1", "1", "2")

y <- c("1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "1", "1", 
"1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "2", "1", "1", "2", "1", 
"2", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "1", NA, 
"2", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", 
"2", "1", "1", "2", "2", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "1", "1", "1", 
NA, "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", 
"1", "1", "1")
```

In table:

```
x
  1   2   3 

121  35   2



y

1   2  NA 

120  36   2
```

To my understanding, the default of chisq.test(x,y,correct = T), so if n < 5 it should do a Pearson's Chi - squared test with Yates correction. But it only does the classic chi squared test.

```
Warning: Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  df$eq_5d_movilidad and df$eq_5d_mov_fin
X-squared = 34.842, df = 2, p-value = 2.718e-08
```

Edit1:
Edited output, as I've selected as levels of each vector ("1","2","3"). Also I tried making a contingency table with package "gmodels":

```
   Cell Contents
|-------------------------|
|                       N |
| Chi-square contribution |
|           N / Row Total |
|           N / Col Total |
|         N / Table Total |
|-------------------------|

 
Total Observations in Table:  158 

 
             | y 
           x |         1 |         2 | Row Total | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
           1 |       106 |        15 |       121 | 
             |     1.691 |     5.731 |           | 
             |     0.876 |     0.124 |     0.766 | 
             |     0.869 |     0.417 |           | 
             |     0.671 |     0.095 |           | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
           2 |        16 |        19 |        35 | 
             |     4.498 |    15.243 |           | 
             |     0.457 |     0.543 |     0.222 | 
             |     0.131 |     0.528 |           | 
             |     0.101 |     0.120 |           | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
           3 |         0 |         2 |         2 | 
             |     1.544 |     5.233 |           | 
             |     0.000 |     1.000 |     0.013 | 
             |     0.000 |     0.056 |           | 
             |     0.000 |     0.013 |           | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
Column Total |       122 |        36 |       158 | 
             |     0.772 |     0.228 |           | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
```

What is happening?

Comment: Use the output of `dput(x)` and `dput(x)` to post data in a copy&paste able format, not the output of `print`, please. Edited.

Comment: I'll do, sorry, thank you for the edit @RuiBarradas.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the error, I'm getting `X-squared = 34.842, df = 2, p-value = 2.718e-08`, which seems to show that the continuity correction is being applied.

Comment: Hello @RuiBarradas, thanks for your answer, normally when I've done a chisq.test in other sets of data, when I've used the test, in the title it gives you the name "with yates correction".  In my last code I also get a chi squared test done, but It doesn't show the test used. I'm looking to be able to see what test is R doing.

Comment: If I'm reading the source correctly, the Yates continuity correction label is not printed if the resulting table is not exactly 2x2, see https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/768e32d10b795d81b52ba511c6ff2030ec0fef66/src/library/stats/R/chisq.test.R#L93-L99

Comment: @r2evans I don't think it's just the label, I think Yates is only applied in the 2x2 case.

Comment: So, if I'm not being mistaken, R automatically does the correction if needed, but the label only is printed when the resulting table is 2x2... Is there any way that I can know when the Yates correction is applied?

Comment: @Axeman I thought as much, but I didn't dive into the code enough to know what tests were being applied, lazy of me. I wanted to be precise in my statement given that laziness so at least I didn't mislead ... thanks for confirming my suspicion!

Comment: @JorgeA Compare `correct = TRUE` with `correct = FALSE`, there is no correction. That's because Yates's correction is only defined for the 2x2 case, as far as I know.

Comment: @Axeman I understand now, then to compare 2 categorical variables with +2 levels, what test should I study?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. That would be a question for stats.stackexchange.com!

Comment: Ok, I'll try my luck, the literature I consulted said to just use chi.squared without correction, but I'm not sure, can u post an answer so i can select it as the correct one?